# There is no enough memory allocated for double pointer but still i can allocate

Tags: c, malloc

I am learning dynamic allocation in C So I tested some codes of mine but having one doubt regarding below code

```
int main(void) {
    char **ptr;
    ptr = malloc(2 * sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { 
        ptr[i] = malloc(2);
    }
    ptr[0] = "he";
    ptr[7] = "hi";
    ptr[8] = "yo";
    printf("%s", ptr[0]);
    printf("%s", ptr[8]);
}
```

Output

```
$ heyo
```

I allocated only 16 bytes ( char* = 8 byte's) so from where extra 2 byte was allocated? How can I allocate memory for ptr[8]? Because 16(bytes)/8(ptr's) = 2 bytes for each ptr ( total 8 ptr's) but still I can allocate memory for 9th.

Comment: Going out of bounds of allocated memory (which you do) leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Besides that, the assignments like e.g. `ptr[0]="he"` will *overwrite* the pointer in `ptr[0]`, making you lose the original pointer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ptr is not declared , this code does not any chance to compile

Comment: Oh and don't forget that `char` strings are really called ***null-terminated** byte string*. That *null-terminated* bit is the character `'\0'` that all strings should be terminated with, also needs space allocated for it. So a string of two characters needs *three* bytes allocated.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but why `yo` was printed ?

Comment: *Undefined behavior* makes all discussion about behavior moot. And it also include the possibility that things might *seem* to work. Lastly, the (invalid!) pointer  in `ptr[8]` is pointing to the first character of the three-element read-only array that contains the literal string `"yo"`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Those 2 bytes that are allocated are never used anyway.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The fact that the C standard does not define the behavior does not make all discussion about behavior moot. The C standard is only one of the things that affects how C programs work. Others include operating systems, linkers, specific C compilers, processor design, and physics. Most humans will not, even cannot, learn C as an abstraction that exists only in a pure form using strictly conforming code. They experiment with C on actual computers, and they need to be able to reason how they results they observe are obtained, even if the conclusion of that reasoning includes…

Comment: … the fact the behavior is not defined by the C standard. Because even if it includes that, it is also shaped by their C implementation. Learning that, if you go beyond what the C standard specifies, you may commonly see this result or that result is informative and useful. And those observations can help you diagnose bugs in the future. And, even if the behavior is not defined by the C standard, seeing how even “broken” programs operates teaches people about things other than the C standard, such as how specific implementations get their jobs done.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You're mixing *undefined* behavior, which is specified in the C specification (the specification will say "this is undefined behavior" or similar wording), and *unspecified* behavior which isn't part of the specification. Then ther's also *implementation specific* behavior, which is also specified as such. Going out of bounds is specified as UB.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: No, I am not. I wrote about what the C standard calls undefined behavior. (Outside of the C standard, it is not undefined behavior; it is merely behavior not defined by the C standard, hence my phrasing.)

Comment: A compiled program using a certain implementation does usually have characteristic behaviour at the same point of machine code. But not even the implementations care not define what the behaviour will be. The only way to properly learn C is to appreciate the fact that it **is** indeed defined in terms of the abstract machine and the generated code is indeed as if it were running inside one.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: That is not the only way to learn C. It is the destination one reaches in order to master C. But no person takes a direct route. The route to learning C takes one on a journey with real-world computers, and one must understand what they observe on this journey in order to progress.

Comment: It is like learning Zen from Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 int main(void) {
     char **ptr;
     ptr = malloc(2 * sizeof(char *));// 2 pointers of chars - 
    //16  bytes
    //After you allocated only 16 bytes  in ptr[0] and ptr[1]
    //you are reaching unallocated cells in ptr (1>i<9)         
    // 9 x 2 bytes - 18 bytes 
     for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { 
         ptr[i] = malloc(2);
     }
    //so the total allocated memory is 16+18 =34
     // all of the next assignmenta will override the address 
    //you recieved from the malloc calls
     ptr[0] = "he";
     ptr[7] = "hi";
     ptr[8] = "yo";
     printf("%s", ptr[0]);
     printf("%s", ptr[8]);
}
```

The code should be:

```
int main(void)   
{
     char **ptr=malloc(9 *sizeof(char *));

     for(int i = 0;i < 9; i++)  
     { 
         ptr[i]=malloc(3);  
     }

     strcpy(ptr[0], "he");  
     strcpy(ptr[1], "hi");
     strcpy(ptr[2], "yo");  
     strcpy(ptr[3], "hi");
     strcpy(ptr[4], "he");  
     strcpy(ptr[5], "yo");
     strcpy(ptr[6], "he");  
     strcpy(ptr[7], "hi");
     strcpy(ptr[8], "yo");  

    return:
 }
```

About the  "extra bytes" allocated,
No extra bytes allocated, the thing is you reached unallocated memory addresses (buffer overflow) and the result was that everything went fine and the strings indeed placed in those spaces.. but it was only because you'r a lucky guy!,  bufferoverflow causes undefined behaiver so dont do that.

Comment: @Dr.Haimovitz now I understand thnx

Answer (score 1):

I have amended the example to show how to allocate, and when you need allocation and when not.

```
#define  NUMBER_OF_STRINGS 9

int main(void)
{
    char **ptr=malloc(NUMBER_OF_STRINGS *sizeof(char *));
    for(int i = 0;i < NUMBER_OF_STRINGS; i++)  
    { 
        ptr[i]=malloc(3);  / "he" == 'h' + 'e' + '\0'
    }


    free(ptr[0]);
    ptr[0]="he";    //memory has not to be allocated as you assign the pointer to the string liteal;
    free(ptr[7]);
    ptr[7]="hi";
    free(ptr[8]);
    ptr[8]="yo";

    strcpy(ptr[1], "he");  //memory has to be allocated as we copy the content of the string liteal
    strcpy(ptr[4], "hi");

    printf("%s",ptr[0]);
    printf("%s",ptr[8]);
```

Comment: @p-j it means ptr[8] is not invalid pointer in case of assigning string literal ? Program will not give any undefined behavior ?

Comment: No as you assign the pointer with pointer. You do not copy anything

Comment: Showing correct code does not answer OP’s questions about how the incorrect code managed to produce the output it did.